# C# windows Form and MYSQL

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I'm Creating movie theater reservation system using C# windows form application.  I'm Using array of buttons to create seat layouts.
However, I came upon roadblock. One functionality of my program is to store customers information into MYSQL database. The program should also keep track of the customer history (reserving, purchasing tickets).  Customer History should be displayed when their profile is opened. This is where I'm having problem.  I have taken taken care of saving and deleting customer's general inf (Name. phone, Email....). I tried to create another table in MYSQL database and save every action performed by the customer. I have also placed a listview in the program (c# windows form) where I plan to place the customer history (upload the info from the database to the listview).

How do I link history with the customer?

I have also tried to create a table containing all the customers name and other information. And for every customer a create a "history table" . But this way would be a problem because I have to create a table for every new customer (to keep their reserved tickets and other histories) which would be a horrible programming (if its possible to create table outside the MYSQL database).

Thanks you
Let me know if the question is not specific enough.

Comment: What you need has nothing to do with anything in your tags or title: You need to learn the basics of database design. Google is your friend and also pen and paper..!  This question is not suitable for this site, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your user has some unique identifier, either a userid, or a guid, or a unique login. 
Let's say you only have the login as unique id, in that case (if you don't want to add an auto_increment userid column) just add a field 'user' to the history table and link them.

The correct way would be to have a foreign key, but, seeing how you seem to be starting, just adding the unique field (or creating a unique field in your user table) and referring to that column from all other tables will do just fine.

Don't forget to index the unique column for speedy lookups ;)

Good luck,

bovako

Comment: Yes, every customer has a userId as a unique identifier.  What I don't understand in your comment is this line 

"field 'user' to the history table and link them."

what do you mean by "field."  Are you proposing that I should create one history table and link it to each customer through this "field."

Thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry, no i meant column. So as long as every table has a column you can join on, you get only the relevant results. 

But, I guess you understood it in the end. :) Thanks for the answer mark. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create an attribute for `customerID` in the table where you store the data every time the a customer purchases a ticket or reservation.

This will be use whenever you need to check on the history of ticket purchases and reservations. All you need to do is to Join the table of the customer via `customerID` in your query with the transaction tables to get the customer name.